# How to get angular customfilter working?

Tags: angularjs, filter

Trying to create a custom angular filter for a list. I am using underscore too:

```
app.filter('dateRangefilter', function($scope,_) {
  return function(input) {
    console.log('rangefilter');
    _.filter($scope.data, function(row) {
      return row.date >= '01/01/2000' && row.date <= '01/08/2020'
    });
  }
});
```

html:

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data | dateRangefilter ">
        {{item.name}}
      </li>
</ul>
```

However I am getting an error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-`beta.14/$injector/unpr?p0=<!-- ngRepeat: item in data | dateRangefilter -->copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%dateRangefilterFilter`
```

How can I get it to filter the data by daterange? in this case between 1/1/2000 and 1/8/2020?

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/oClJWLaw13Xl2UDxn0Vp?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the second parameter of the `filter` should be an empty function. Remove that, since you don't really need the `$scope` and `_` (you have them already). And modify to achieve this:

```
app.filter('dateRangefilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return _.filter(input, function (d) {
      return Date.parse(d.date) >= Date.parse('01/01/2000') && Date.parse(d.date) <= Date.parse('01/08/2020');
    });
  }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aJnkUD7GnwDjyMvKfdav?p=preview)

Modification points:

1. Make sure to also return the `_.filter`.
2. You can't compare dates when they are in string format. (I mean you can, but the result might not be what you expect it to be)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a method defined at `$scope`. See here http://plnkr.co/edit/FBcfAZQ9QMdQiWdEsjMk?p=preview

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:dateRangefilter ">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.dateRangefilter = function(input) {
  console.log(input);
  return input.date >= '01/01/2000' && input.date <= '01/08/2020'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

1. In your underscore model, you didn't finish injecting `$window`. You must also pass it to the function itself:

   ```
   underscore.factory('_', ['$window', function() {})
   ```

   Needs to turn to:

   ```
   underscore.factory('_', ['$window', function($window) {})
   ```
2. You need to return the final value from the filter as well
3. You can't compare dates as strings. Here's the final function:

   ```
   app.filter('dateRangefilter', function(_) { // don't need $scope. It's irrelevant for a filter
     return function(input) {
       console.log('rangefilter');
       return _.filter(input, function(row) { // needed to return this as well
         var date = new Date(row.date);
         var from = new Date('01/01/2000');
         var to   = new Date('01/08/2020');
         return date >= from && date <= to; // dates can be compared properly
       });
     }
   });
   ```